# for loop only shows last iteration

Tags: c, loops, for-loop

I created the most simple program, yet it only shows the last iteration of the loop. I've never had this problem before, so maybe that's why I can't see what's wrong. any help will be appreciated

```
int main() {

int number = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        printf("enter number: ");
        scanf("%d", &number);
    }  
    printf("Displaying entered information:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        printf("number: %d\n", number);
    }
}
```

Comment: You only have a single `number` you store. You probably want to have an array of `int` you read into

Comment: In the second pass through the loop, `scanf("%d", &number);` overwrites the number that you obtained in the first pass though the loop. "Use it or lose it" applies to such values. In this case, you didn't use it, so you lost it.

Comment: I really don't understand the purpose of this code

Comment: you need to `#include <stdio.h>` or suffer the wrath of undefined behaviour

Comment: @JohnColeman Yes I know. It's just that I don't understand what it is intended to do.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us what out put you expect for a given input. Don't describe it but show a simple use case.

Answer (score 4):

Just input and display in the same scope...

```
int main() {

    int number = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        printf("enter number: ");
        scanf("%d", &number);
        printf("Displaying entered information:\n");
        printf("number: %d\n", number);
    }
}
```

Comment: When I see your user name I want to respond with `c6`

Comment: And I usually answer with `c3` ;-)

Comment: `d5` -- but the "avoid long discussions in comments" nag will pop up long before a whole game is played.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing the following:

Read a number.
Overwrite that number.
Show the last number (by the value is has been overwritten).

This indeed gives you the idea that only the last loop is executed, but it's not the case.

You can put everything in the same loop and you'll see everything will be done fine:

```
int number = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        printf("enter number: ");
        scanf("%d", &number);
        printf("Displaying entered information:\n");
        printf("number: %d\n", number);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

And if you want to have it as an array and with define and some changes you can make it dynamic:

```
#define INPUT_SIZE 2

int main() {

    int number[INPUT_SIZE];

    for (int i = 0; i < INPUT_SIZE; i++)
    {
        printf("enter number: ");
        scanf("%d", &number[i]);
    }

    printf("Displaying entered information:\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < INPUT_SIZE; i++)
    {
        printf("number: %d\n", number[i]);
    }
}
```